# cannot change resource template after migration

Tags: modx-revolution

After migrating to a new server I have found that I cannot change template: page reloaded but the template remains the same as it was.

Have I forgotten to do something after migration?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There may be few reasons for this to happen but the most common and most likely to happen is the variance of the time interpreted by MODX and time that server is set to. This means that whenever document is edited, MODX caches its content and differentiates each of these cached files by timestamp. Once reloaded, MODX tries to retrieve the timestamp and compare it and if fails, it jumps the form content (including the template settings) to the previous settings.

The solution for that is to get the date.timezone setting from the server configuration and paste it into date_time setting in the MODX manager settings to make them equal. This should solve the problem right away but keep in mind that the cache cleanup(even manaual) may be needed.